# scheduling a windows service without using the task scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a windows service that archives files from a paticular folder. I want the program to run everday at a specific time. I can do that using the task scheduler. what I want to do is to schedule the task without actually assessing the windows task scheduler GUI. Maybe a batch script that schedules the program to run every day even when the system is on sleep or maybe something else i can do?
does anyone have an idea of how this thing can be implemented?

Comment: There are so many, many options. 
How about simply making a cron job?

Comment: schtasks.exe (or at.exe) is the command line interface to the Task Scheduler service.

Comment: Google: https://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/
@HimBromBeere: If you read the question properly you see that it does say that he is open to use task scheduler, he just doesn't want to use its GUI. Personally I find the Task Scheduler GUI confusing and hard to navigate.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know i can use the scheduller but it is just if i want an alternative to the same thing. its just a simple exercise that i need to do

Comment: @mortb thanks mate this does help. but I was curious that do i have to run the same command everytime i want the task to be performed or just initialize it once ? and will it execute when the system/server is on sleep or if rebooted?

Comment: @lewis: If you run for example `SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN “My Task” /TR “C:RunMe.bat” /ST 09:00` (from the link) you will create a task that runs every day at 9:00. You just need to run the console command once. The task will be run everyday at 9:00 until you delete (or disable) the task

Comment: @mortb ok. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty basic . so the thing is that instead of using the task scheduler we are creating a scheduler itself in our code so there is a thread that will be created that will always be checking for the time that I want my actual code to run and once the current time is the time that I want the method to run it will trigger the main program(in the example the method I want to trigger is named ArchiveFile) . 
so first in the OnStart I am setting a new timer and want it to fire 24x7,every hour.
then in the timer_elapse i want to check if the current time is the time I want my method to execute and if true it will call the method that I want to execute.(in this example I have set the time to be 9 pm or 21 hours)

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();                                        
        timer.Interval = 36000;                                                   // that fires every hour    
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);    //calling the elapse event when the timer elapses
        timer.AutoReset = true;                                                   // AutoReset is set to true as we want the timer to fire 24x7 so that the elapse event is executed only at the requried time  
        timer.Enabled = true;                                                                                                   

    }
    protected void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)       //everytime the elapse event occurs the TimeCheck method will be called 
    {
        TimeCheck();    
    }

    public void TimeCheck()    //method to check if the current time is the time we want the archiving to occur
    {

        var dt = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        if(dt==21)
        {
            Archivefile();
        }

    }
```

Comment: please note that this is not an optimised way of doing a task as the thread i have created is always holding a memory and the task scheduler has a same working . but this was done just to get a conceptual hold .

Comment: Found this by accident for an issue I am having with Task Scheduler always giving me a "Launch request ignored" Warning and I am sure my exe never runs. Would a Windows Service with a constant thread be a better way to go to avoid these Task Scheduler issues. I am sure the process is not running at the time of the requested start time.