# Schedule a Batch (.bat) File to Run Without Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

**UPDATE 2:** I still haven't found a way to "schedule" my file to run, but I did find a line of code to add to the end of my code that will shutdown my computer. So I can run my .bat file (backups) at the end of the day and walk away without having to go back and shutdown. I hope this helps someone if they come across this thread. If someone comes across this and knows how to schedule my file I would REALLY appreciate your help!

```
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

**UPDATE 1:** I forgot to mention that I intend on placing the .bat file in my startup folder so it starts to run every morning when I start my computer. The problem I am having is that the timer/schedule code I found doesn't seem to be executing at the specified time. Thank you all in advance for any help you can provide.

**Problem:** I have a batch (.bat) file that I want to run everyday at the end of the workday that will create copies of my files so I have backups, for my own peace of mind and security. This is for work and I do not have access to use Task Scheduler, nor can I download new software.

**What I've Tried:**

First, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289811/scheduling-a-windows-service-without-using-the-task-scheduler) post, with code that didn't seem quite right for a .bat file but I figured I would try it (slightly modified for my needs):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();                                        
        timer.Interval = 36000;                                                    // that fires every hour    
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);    //calling the elapse event when the timer elapses
        timer.AutoReset = true;                                                   // AutoReset is set to true as we want the timer to fire 24x7 so that the elapse event is executed only at the requried time  
        timer.Enabled = true;                                                                                                   
}
protected void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)       //everytime the elapse event occurs the TimeCheck method will be called 
{
        TimeCheck();    
}
public void TimeCheck()    //method to check if the current time is the time we want the archiving to occur
{
        var dt = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        if(dt==17)
        {
                Call path\backups.bat
        }
}
```

I like the concept, but I tried it and I get a plethora of errors, the very first of which is `'protected' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Am I missing something that would make this work? Also, the person that posted the answer says that it is not an optimized solution. Is there an optimized way to go about this? I don't want to bog my computer down any more than I have to.

Second, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861172/how-to-schedule-running-a-bat-file-not-using-windows-task-scheduler) post, which seemed to have promising code (slightly modified for my needs):

```
@echo off
:loop
set timeHrs=%time:~0,2%
set timeMin=%time:~3,2%
set timeSec=%time:~6,2%

timeout /t 3600

if "%timeHrs%" geq 17 if "%timeHrs%" leq 18 [Call path\backups.bat]
goto loop
```

This seems straightforward (if I am understanding it correctly) but it seems to get through the timeout counter but then even if the time falls in the range the code to run the backup file doesn't run, it just starts the timeout again. Also, is there a way to set it so it only runs if timeHrs is exactly equal to a number (i.e. 17 = 5PM)? Note, I tested this code with numbers where my current time would have fallen in the range, not the range listed above. The range listed above is just the range that this code would ideally run.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: You can't just paste C# into a batch file and expect it to work; they're two completely different languages.

Comment: How is your script supposed to know what time to run itself? The obvious way it to have the script run on login, either automatically through the startup location or registry run key. However, it would have to keep checking the time, at reasonable intervals, to ensure that it can perform your backup at around the time you require it. Alternatively, you could create a script which you manually run, to perform the backup, and turn off/log out each evening when you finish.

Comment: There are certain folders that start items in it on startup or login. Not sure if you could schedule things till the end of the day, but it might help. Search up `shell:startup` and `shell:common startup` or use `start "shell:startup"` and `start "shell:common startup"`. You should put your finished batch file in one of them so it starts on bootup (`shell:common startup`) or login of a specific user (`shell:startup`)

Comment: @SomethingDark I didn't realize that was C# code, that explains why it looked different and didn't work. I thought maybe it was a different language but I wasn't sure. Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for the suggestions. I was planning on putting my script in the startup folder so it runs whenever I start my computer in the morning and just checks the time every hour. I already have a script that I run manually, I was trying to automate because I don't always remember to run it and I also don't want to have to keep checking if it was done so I can logoff and shutdown. I didn't realize I could use a .bat to turn off my computer. Would you mind providing the code snippet that would do that? I would greatly appreciate it. That would at least solve one of my dilemmas.

Comment: @NekoMusume Thank you for the insights, I meant to put in my post that I would be placing my .bat file in the startup folder. I will update my post now to make sure I clarify that. Thank you.

Comment: @britnysarver, most people use the `shutdown` command, with its `/S` option. You can find out more by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `help shutdown`, and pressing the 'ENTER' key. If you take that route, it should be properly used with the `/D` option, examples are: `%__AppDir__%shutdown.exe /S /D P:4:1`, or on [tag:Windows10], `%__AppDir__%shutdown.exe /S /Soft /D P:4:1`. Alternatively you can use [tag:WMIC], examples of which could be: `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Where "Status='OK'" Call Win32Shutdown 1` or `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe OS Where "Status='OK'" Call Win32Shutdown 8`.

Comment: @Compo Thank you for the information. I found the line of code I need. I added it to my post in case someone else can use it, `shutdown /s /f /t 0`. This helps a lot. At least now all I have to do is remember to double-click my file at the end of the day.

Comment: @britnysarver, I would also advise you not to force close applications, with no time-out period, you have no idea what programs the end user is running, or whether those will lose unsaved data. At the very least just use `%__AppDir__%shutdown.exe /S`, which should imply force closure, with a defualt time-out period of 30 seconds. Preferably in that case, I'd suggest that you use `%__AppDir__%shutdown.exe /S /C "Please save your current work, this PC is shutting down"`, to give them time to save things themselves.

Comment: @Compo If I ever use this for someone else I will keep that in mind. Thank you! As it stands, I'm running this only on my pc when I'm done for the day so everything is saved and closed. That should be ok, right?